# is there a way to use a variable from one function to another? -Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function GradingScheme()
{

  var quiz1, quiz2, quiz3, ass1, ass2, lab1, lab2, lab3, pegrade;


   quiz1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quiz1").value);
   quiz2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quiz2").value);
   quiz3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quiz3").value);
   ass1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ass1").value);
   ass2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ass2").value);
   lab1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lab1").value);
   lab2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lab2").value);
   lab3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lab3").value);
   pegrade = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pegrade").value);
  
quiz4 = ((quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3) / 3 );
ass3 = ((ass1 + ass2) / 2 );
lab4 = ((lab1 + lab2 + lab3) / 3 );
 
  var cs = ((quiz4 * 0.60) + (ass3 * 0.20) + (lab4 * 0.20) );
  var pg = (cs*.50) + (pegrade*.50);
 

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your Prelim grade is: " + pg.toFixed(1);

} 

  function MIDTERM()
  {
  


     quiz1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2quiz1").value);
     quiz2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2quiz2").value);
     quiz3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2quiz3").value);
     ass1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2ass1").value);
     ass2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2ass2").value);
     lab1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2lab1").value);
     lab2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2lab2").value);
     lab3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2lab3").value);
     Midterm = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mgrade").value);
    
  quiz4 = ((quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3) / 3 );
  ass3 = ((ass1 + ass2) / 2 );
  lab4 = ((lab1 + lab2 + lab3) / 3 );
   
    var cs = ((quiz4 * 0.60) + (ass3 * 0.20) + (lab4 * 0.20));
    var tmg = (cs *.50) + (Midterm *.50);
    mg = (1/3*pg) + (2/3*tmg)
   
  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your Midterm grade is: " + mg.toFixed(1);
  
  }
```

I wish to use the computed pg variable from the GradingScheme function for the MIDTERM function formula.
 `var pg = (cs*.50) + (pegrade*.50);`
The midterm function formula would be like this:
`var cs = ((quiz4 * 0.60) + (ass3 * 0.20) + (lab4 * 0.20)); var tmg = (cs *.50) + (Midterm *.50); mg = (1/3*pg) + (2/3*tmg);`

However, I do not know how to get the pg value from the previous function.

I am still new to JavaScript, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can declare the variable that you want to be shared in the outer scope (outside of any function).

Comment: Instead of having these functions modify the innerHTML of elements on the page directly, you should rather make them return the calculated value. Then you can _call_ `GradingScheme` in `MIDTERM`, to get the value in that place. Or you could of course also make your `MIDTERM` take this value as a parameter - then you don't have to call the other function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use the calculation of `pg` in 2 places, it would make sense to separate out the logic for calculating it into its own function:

```
function calculatePG(){
   var quiz1, quiz2, quiz3, ass1, ass2, lab1, lab2, lab3, pegrade;

   quiz1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quiz1").value);
   quiz2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quiz2").value);
   quiz3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quiz3").value);
   ass1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ass1").value);
   ass2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("ass2").value);
   lab1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lab1").value);
   lab2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lab2").value);
   lab3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lab3").value);
   pegrade = parseFloat(document.getElementById("pegrade").value);
  
  quiz4 = ((quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3) / 3 );
  ass3 = ((ass1 + ass2) / 2 );
  lab4 = ((lab1 + lab2 + lab3) / 3 );
 
  var cs = ((quiz4 * 0.60) + (ass3 * 0.20) + (lab4 * 0.20) );
  return (cs*.50) + (pegrade*.50);
}
```

You can then use this in 2 places

```
function GradingScheme()
{
  varpg = calculatePG();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your Prelim grade is: " + pg.toFixed(1);
} 

function MIDTERM()
{
     quiz1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2quiz1").value);
     quiz2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2quiz2").value);
     quiz3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2quiz3").value);
     ass1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2ass1").value);
     ass2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2ass2").value);
     lab1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2lab1").value);
     lab2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2lab2").value);
     lab3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("2lab3").value);
     Midterm = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mgrade").value);
    
    quiz4 = ((quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3) / 3 );
    ass3 = ((ass1 + ass2) / 2 );
    lab4 = ((lab1 + lab2 + lab3) / 3 );
   
    var cs = ((quiz4 * 0.60) + (ass3 * 0.20) + (lab4 * 0.20));
    var tmg = (cs *.50) + (Midterm *.50);

    var pg = calcuylatePG();
    mg = (1/3*pg) + (2/3*tmg)   
  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your Midterm grade is: " + mg.toFixed(1);  
}
```

There arwe furrther improvments that can be made to your code - generally separate out code which reads/updates the UI from code which does calculations. But the above should get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your answer!